# How to target an element that is being clicked in a class inside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tree, parent

I want to target some div in a class, i would use $(this), but that doesn't doesnt work since im calling that class from another function.

**Sample Code.**

```
$(document).on('click', '.Player', function(e){
    var id = $(this).find('.Song_Id').html();
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: {data:id},
    complete: function(){
    $(this).attr('src', '../images/appicons/2/16x16/refresh - Red.png') 
    },
    url:"php/player/get_song.php"
    }).done(function(f){
        $('#Song_info').html(f)
    });
})
```

From above, the following is the line i don't know how to impliment.

```
$(this).attr('src', '../images/appicons/2/16x16/refresh - Red.png'),
```

it suppose to target class ".player", but not the entire class, only the element that was clicked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the ajax callback is executed, by default the execution context of the callback method is set to the ajax settings object.

You can use the context option of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to pass a custom execution context

```
$(document).on('click', '.Player', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).find('.Song_Id').html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: id
        },
        //use context to set the execution context of the callback
        context: this,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).attr('src', '../images/appicons/2/16x16/refresh - Red.png')
        },
        url: "php/player/get_song.php"
    }).done(function (f) {
        $('#Song_info').html(f)
    });
})
```

[context:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will
>   make that the context for the complete callback of a request

Answer (score 2):

You can store `$(this)` inside another variable and use this variable inside your function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.Player', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).find('.Song_Id').html(),
        that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: id
        },
        complete: function () {
            that.attr('src', '../images/appicons/2/16x16/refresh - Red.png')
        },
        url: "php/player/get_song.php"
    }).done(function (f) {
        $('#Song_info').html(f)
    });
})
```